# Calendar Table For Time Scale Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a schedulle with that pattern
[image]

into a dinamic table,  like this

[image]

what i tryed :

```
date = FILTER(CALENDARAUTO(12),[DATE] >=2022)
```

```
isDayOff = 

var iniDayOff1 = DATE(2022,12,5)
var iniDayOff2 = DATE(2022,12,8)

return IF( WEEKNUM([DATE])+WEEKDAY(IniDayOff1)-2 ||  WEEKNUM([DATE])+WEEKDAY(IniDayOff2)-2 = WEEKDAY([DATE]), "X", )
```

My problem is when WEEKNUM([DATE])+WEEKDAY(IniDayOff1)-2 is bigger then 7, i need that formula to reset, because when dayoff is saturday (WEEKDAY 7), the next dayoff is sunday (WEEKDAY 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula instead:

```
isDayOff = 
VAR iniDayOff1 = DATE(2022, 12, 5)
VAR iniDayOff2 = DATE(2022, 12, 8)
RETURN
    IF(
        MOD(DATEDIFF(IniDayOff1, 'date'[Date], DAY), 8) = 0
        || MOD(DATEDIFF(IniDayOff2, 'date'[Date], DAY), 8) = 0,
        "X",
        BLANK()
    )
```

[image]